# Multipeer Connectivity With Multiple VC

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, sprite-kit, skscene

I currently have a view controller designated to connect two devices together using the multipeer connectivity framework from Apple. Everything connects fine and messages can be sent between the two devices. Once they two devices are connected and you hit a start button, both devices transition to another view controller presenting a SKScene (this is a game app). I want the SKScene to be able to also send and receive messages, however when transitioning to the new VC/SKScene, the connection is lost. Is there a way to keep the connection between view controllers and the SKScene?

```
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
if (!skView.scene) {
    //skView.showsFPS = YES;
    //skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    //skView.showsPhysics = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [gameMyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    [scene.userData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.isMulti] forKey:@"Game"];
    [scene.userData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.isAttack]        forKey:@"Attack"];
    [scene.userData setObject:self.appD forKey:@"AppDel"]; 
    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

This is how my scene is presented in the viewWillLayoutSubviews of a view controller named "gameViewController". The view controller that is handling the connections is called "ConnectGameViewController" which transitions to "gameViewController" when the start button is pressed.

Comment: You will need to post some code related to the declaration and presentation of the SKScene from the VC

Comment: Also, provide some detail as to where you are creating and holding the multi peer session.  This should be in your app delegate or another singleton class.  If you are doing it in your first view controller, you are probably losing the session when that object goes out of scope

Comment: Right, totally forgot. So my gameAppDelegate (it's a sprite kit project) creates an instance of a class called MPCHandler which is the MCSessionDelegate. This contains the code setting up a browser, receiving data etc. The ConnectGameViewContoller is the MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate, which is where all the advertising and such is actually taking place (methods called from mpcHandler)

Comment: Got it, was setting my app delegate in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I had a difficult time finding a clear solution, so heres what I found:

1. Create a cocoa touch class(MPC class) to handle your sessions, peerID... Also import MultipeerConnectivity and define your class as a NSObject, and MCSessionDelegate:

.

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity
class mpc: NSObject, MCSessionDelegate {

    var peerID:MCPeerID!
    var session:MCSession!
    var browser:MCBrowserViewController!
    var advertiser:MCAdvertiserAssistant? = nil

    func setupPeerWithDisplayName (displayName:String){
        peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: displayName)
    }

    func setupSession(){
        session = MCSession(peer: peerID)
        session.delegate = self
    }

    func setupBrowser(){
        browser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "ADDCONNECTIONNAME", session: session)

    }

    func advertiseSelf(advertise:Bool){
        if advertise{
            advertiser = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "ADDCONNECTIONNAME", discoveryInfo: nil, session: session)
            advertiser!.start()
        }else{
            advertiser!.stop()
            advertiser = nil
        }
    }

    func sendData (variable: String, data: AnyObject, sendTo: AnyObject){
        //Send Data
        let archived = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject([variable : data])
        do{
            try session.sendData(archived, toPeers: session.connectedPeers, withMode: .Unreliable)
        }catch _ as NSError {
            print("Error: Cannot send Message.")
        }

    }

    func session(session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChangeState state: MCSessionState) {

    }

    func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    //Receive Data
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            let archived = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            if archived.indexForKey("Variable1") != nil {
                let data = archived["Variable1"] //as! [String],Int,Bool...

            }else if archived.indexForKey("Variable2") != nil {
                let data = archived["Variable2"] //as! [String],Int,Bool...
            }
        }   
    }

    func session(session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, atURL localURL: NSURL, withError error: NSError?) {

    }

    func session(session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withProgress progress: NSProgress) {

    }

    func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveStream stream: NSInputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {

    }  
}
```

2. Reference the MPC class you created above in your App Delegate.:

   ```
    var MPC:mpc = mpc()
   ```
3. In your first view controller globalize a reference to your App Delegate:

   ```
   var appDelegate:AppDelegate!
   ```
4. Place the following code in your viewDidLoad(). It will only run once or else it will reset the connection:

   ```
   func willRunOnce() -> () {
       struct TokenContainer {
           static var token : dispatch_once_t = 0
       }

       dispatch_once(&TokenContainer.token) {
           appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
           appDelegate.MPC.setupPeerWithDisplayName(UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
           appDelegate.MPC.setupSession()
           appDelegate.MPC.advertiseSelf(true)
   }
   ```

   }
5. Lastly you can call any function or variable in the MPC class with the following format:

   ```
   appDelegate.MPC.//FUNCTION(),VARIABLE...
   ```